# Rewrite mediawiki links to dokuwiki

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, mediawiki, dokuwiki

I need help with URL rewriting.

I have given up on mediawiki due to all spam bots. I managed to convert all articles to dokuwiki and is now stuck on redirecting old links.

The article title is

```
Namespace:category/page
```

The old link is

```
http://www.mediawikilink.com/?title=Namespace%3Acategory%2Fpage
```

The new link is

```
http://www.dokuwikilink.com/?id=Namespace%3Acategory%2Fpage
```

I tried the following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Ending up with a bad result:

```
doku.php?id=Namespace%253Acategory%252Fpage
URL decoded: Namespace_3a_category_2f_page
```

I believe the problem lies within RewriteCond parsing raw non-decoded values and RewriteRule encodes it over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this better ?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dokuwikilink.com$1?id=%1? [NE,R=301,L]
```

[NE: noescape.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html)